# APYDataGridBundle error

Tags: php, symfony

After I installed this bundle and I'm using in controller follow code:

```
use APY\DataGridBundle\Grid\Source\Vector;
......
$source = new Vector($deliveries);
$grid = $this->get('grid');
```

Row with $source.... works normal. I tried var_dump($source) and saw the right data. But second row gave me next error:

```
You have requested a non-existent service "request". Did you mean one of these: "router.request_context", "request_stack", "monolog.logger.request", "validate_request_listener", "data_collector.request"?
```

What need I to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. For Symfony > 2.8 need use this bundle

https://github.com/artscorestudio/APYDataGridBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md